# SQL Server database project - Create change scripts

Tags: sql-server, database-project

We started using SQL Server database project in Visual Studio 2012 by connecting an existing database. We are developing a web application that connects with this database.

Now we have around twenty stored procedures updated for the next release. How can I create a script file that contains only the updated stored procedures? We need to send this script to our clients along with the Web application executable files.

Is there any feature that allows us to compare and create only the changed scripts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use this query to get the procedurename which was modified by last 30 days `SELECT * FROM SYS.Procedures where Modify_date > Getdate() -30` . for change script you can use source control  like SVN,VSS etc .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Schema Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx) as follows:

1. Create a Schema Comparison that compares the database project to one of the production databases.
2. Run the schema compare.
3. Exclude everything except for the stored procedures (plus any objects on which they depend).
4. Click Generate Script.

If you save this Schema Comparison then you can reuse it the next time you need to publish more stored procedure changes.

Comment: You _may_ need to include schemas. I remember having an issue in the past w/ compares if I didn't include the "schema" option. Nothing would show up until I checked that.